# Safe Programming of Pthreads on PIN-Using Simulators

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, pthread-join, intel-pin

I'm using an hardware simulator which uses PIN Tools to execute the workload. As the workload, I'm using the following code. Although it works on Ubuntu with **-lpthread** flag, it freezes on the simulator when it comes to join threads.

I think there is something not safe in this code which native OS can tolerate but simulator cannot. What is the most appropriate way to code this?

**main.h:**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

#define NUM_OF_VERTICES 4
#define NUM_OF_PTHREADS (NUM_OF_VERTICES*(NUM_OF_VERTICES-1)/2)

std::string payload_texts[NUM_OF_VERTICES];
void payload_text_initialize();
double indices [NUM_OF_VERTICES][NUM_OF_VERTICES];

class thread_args {   
    public: 
        uint index1, index2;
        unsigned  long value = 0;
        unsigned  long * valuePointer = &value;
};
```

**main.cc:**

```
#include "main.h"

extern "C" {
    extern void mcsim_skip_instrs_begin();
    extern void mcsim_skip_instrs_end();
    extern void mcsim_spinning_begin();
    extern void mcsim_spinning_end();
    int32_t log_2(uint64_t);
}

using namespace std;

set<char> find_uniques(string str){
    set<char> unique_chars;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++ ){
        char c = str.at(i);
        if (unique_chars.find(c) == unique_chars.end())
            unique_chars.insert(c);
    }
    return unique_chars;
}

void * jaccard_visit(void *arg){
    thread_args * args = (thread_args *) arg;
    set<char> setunion;
    set<char> intersect;

    set<char> set1 = find_uniques(payload_texts[args->index1]);
    set<char> set2 = find_uniques(payload_texts[args->index2]);


    std::set_intersection(set1.begin(),set1.end(),set2.begin(),set2.end(),std::inserter(intersect,intersect.begin()));
    std::set_union(set1.begin(),set1.end(),set2.begin(),set2.end(),std::inserter(setunion,setunion.begin()));

    double similarity = ((double) intersect.size()) / ((double) setunion.size());
    indices[args->index1][args->index2] = similarity;
    indices[args->index2][args->index1] = similarity;

    unsigned long a = 1;
    unsigned long b = 1;
    unsigned long c = a + b;
    for (int i = 3 ; i < 100000 * (similarity - 0.9) ; i++){
        a = b;
        b = c; 
        c = a + b;
    }

    *(args->valuePointer) = c;

    return NULL;
}

void execute_parallel(){      
    pthread_t threads[NUM_OF_PTHREADS]; //array to hold thread information 
    thread_args *th_args = (thread_args*) malloc(NUM_OF_PTHREADS * sizeof(thread_args)); 

    cout << "NUM_OF_PTHREADS is " << NUM_OF_PTHREADS << endl;
    uint k = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_VERTICES ; i++){
        for (int j = i+1 ; j < NUM_OF_VERTICES ; j++){
            th_args[k].index1 = i;
            th_args[k].index2 = j;
            th_args[k].value = i+j; 
            th_args[k].valuePointer = &(th_args[k].value);
            pthread_create(&threads[k], NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &th_args[k]);
            cout << "Thread " << k << " is started" << endl;
            k++;
        }
    }

    cout << "k is " << k << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_PTHREADS; i++){ 
        cout << "Thread " << i << " is joined" << endl;
        pthread_join(threads[i], NULL); 
    } 

    cout << "Free threads" << endl ;

    free(th_args); 

} 

void manual_schedule(){
    pthread_t th0, th1, th2, th3, th4, th5;
    thread_args arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5;

    arg0.index1 = 0;    arg0.index2 = 1;    arg0.value = 0; arg0.valuePointer = &arg0.value;
    arg1.index1 = 0;    arg1.index2 = 2;    arg1.value = 1; arg1.valuePointer = &arg1.value;
    arg2.index1 = 0;    arg2.index2 = 3;    arg2.value = 2; arg2.valuePointer = &arg2.value;
    arg3.index1 = 1;    arg3.index2 = 2;    arg3.value = 3; arg3.valuePointer = &arg3.value;
    arg4.index1 = 1;    arg4.index2 = 3;    arg4.value = 4; arg4.valuePointer = &arg4.value;
    arg5.index1 = 2;    arg5.index2 = 3;    arg5.value = 5; arg5.valuePointer = &arg5.value;

    cout << "Arguments are done ";

    pthread_create(&th0, NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &arg0);
    pthread_create(&th1, NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &arg1);
    pthread_create(&th2, NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &arg2);
    pthread_create(&th3, NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &arg3);
    pthread_create(&th4, NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &arg4);
    pthread_create(&th5, NULL, jaccard_visit, (void*) &arg5);

    cout << "Threads are created" << endl;

    cout << "Join starts here" << endl;
    pthread_join(th0, NULL); 
    pthread_join(th1, NULL); 
    pthread_join(th2, NULL); 
    pthread_join(th3, NULL); 
    pthread_join(th4, NULL); 
    pthread_join(th5, NULL); 

    cout << "Fibonaccis: " <<endl;
    cout << *(arg0.valuePointer) << endl;
    cout << *(arg1.valuePointer) << endl;
    cout << *(arg2.valuePointer) << endl;
    cout << *(arg3.valuePointer) << endl;
    cout << *(arg4.valuePointer) << endl;
    cout << *(arg5.valuePointer) << endl;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    cout << "Jaccard process is started"<<endl;
    mcsim_skip_instrs_begin();
    payload_text_initialize();
    mcsim_skip_instrs_end();

    cout << "Parallel part begins"<< endl;
    manual_schedule();

    cout << "Calculated results are being logged"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < NUM_OF_VERTICES ; i++){
        for (int j = 0 ; j < NUM_OF_VERTICES ; j++){
            cout << indices[i][j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}



void payload_text_initialize(){
    payload_texts[0] = "l5IC5uC9AzcROkE3YkDJ2lEzLts8XP8a9WqDgDLWjg1M7HysAUfDFwzLWjc7875PnZVUHLzi6nQaUMQDNUeG4Wn2UkiOB79tOlE1t6LaKYbYiCJwJ34CAOFZCIbFSmcLTAAoB1rvPfeA6oM3kV3C8BDvraGvXjUORLGFAcBRQCerb3WD0qhrrM0MVW0t93bBqlTsrkxg";
    payload_texts[1] = "tILKwAhbUkoqouKZ1G1VrZRmKwQnwzBgQirLkdedsYIAplKdEfk8oSmqdJmCJd5g0Q3VcJ8RYoxtIwA7jL1L01DcagIOuld0whcyM0yvSP0pMWO2yVTwOQPGkW2k7AHqzSEvb5BWkKsTexBsCUepjbG50T6vKsEHXGJ9aZwn2274Ekhnu1hlvuTqsS8jgwr0kQwhbwxN";
    payload_texts[2] = "LNyQgx3mox3szmRNn1tSB4ibVuLsTr7MfANlj41Y0hKStx3NJx1O52XxNiqTMDCu4eGwWYcBvFMEC5tl1E7Rsm0Q9NZsPAJIwuiPYQuXeUyhMmbFiwRk6PlziXne0QaFJ3TrncsHsL3LxIDyaDPScSRdEvX72IJmi2gQTHgASi0KkKH4Sr6VJV3FjdNjKwY2ncT5oSXZ";
    payload_texts[3] = "UxynTAvEWF4CcY9wUJRFnrX7sgrvvubcXUqH5DXK12UjSHDUME397S3BdB38FeMQJq8r7P7RILAY0qkw7OxUhGsZHRPmuY7VwKULqb6fx0Oy2McW2u07yqdAEMCN6AkQ1jTn2sXB4uWH21uLbjCf9i2V7W9tyw3cx6piE7XJb3vfbLI34OG5LKQXmVAGT0D6nbibaN8M";
}
```

`execute_parallel()` contains 2 for loops to create and join pthreads. `manual_schedule()` has the unrolled version of the same code. While executing on PIN, both works well until the join function of the first thread. When join comes, it freezes and stays like that forever, without any signal or error. While executing on Ubuntu with **-lpthread** flag, it works perfect and generates the results.

What could be the most safe and appropriate way to implement pthreads in this situation?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

I noticed that program freezes before reading `payload_texts[args->index1]`. Adding a mutex helped to proceed at that point. Also it worked for one time properly. It is non-deterministic now, in multiple executions of the same binary it rarely finishes properly. I think there is supposed to be a reason for a deadlock inside the jaccard_visit function. I changed it like the following:

```
void * jaccard_visit(void *arg){
    thread_args * args = (thread_args *) arg;
    set<char> setunion;
    set<char> intersect;
    int id = args->index1 * 10 + args->index2;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << "Thread "<< id << " started with indices: " << args->index1 << " " << args->index2 << endl;     pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&payload_mutex);
    set<char> set1 = find_uniques(payload_texts[args->index1]);
    set<char> set2 = find_uniques(payload_texts[args->index2]);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&payload_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : payload_texts were read" << endl;         pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : intersect was created, scan begins" << endl;         pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
    for (set<char>::iterator i = set1.begin(); i != set1.end(); i++) {
        char c1 = *i;
        for (set<char>::iterator j = set2.begin(); j != set2.end(); j++) {
            char c2 = *j;
            if (c1 == c2){
                intersect.insert(c1);
                pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : char" << c1 << " was inserted to intersection" << endl;         pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : intersection is calculated" << endl;     pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
    for (set<char>::iterator i = set1.begin(); i != set1.end(); i++) {
        setunion.insert(*i);
    }
    for (set<char>::iterator i = set2.begin(); i != set2.end(); i++) {
        char c = *i;
        bool exists = false;
        for (set<char>::iterator j = set1.begin(); j != set1.end(); j++) {
            if (c == *j)
                exists = true;
        }
        if (exists == false)
            setunion.insert(c);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : union is calculated" << endl;            pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);


    double similarity = ((double) intersect.size()) / ((double) setunion.size());
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);
    cout << id << " : similarity is calculated as " << similarity << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
    indices[args->index1][args->index2] = similarity;
    indices[args->index2][args->index1] = similarity;

    unsigned long a = 1;
    unsigned long b = 1;
    unsigned long c = a + b;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);
    cout << id << " : fibonacci starts" << endl;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    for (int i = 3 ; i < 100000 * (similarity - 0.9) ; i++){
        a = b;
        b = c; 
        c = a + b;
    }
    *(args->valuePointer) = c;

    //pthread_exit(args->valuePointer);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I cannot really remember. But I think on some systems, ``pthread_exit()`` was really required at the end of a thread function. Does it behave the same if you do it that way?

Comment: Thanks @BitTickler, I've just tried `pthread_exit()`. Unfortunately it behaves the same.

Comment: I can't see anything that's obviously unsafe here. I do have two suggestions: first, you should try to create a minimal example that still reproduces the issue. Second, simulation can have a drastic overhead. Are you sure the test hangs? Maybe it just takes a lot longer.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any reason to use `valuePointer`, you could remove that and just have the thread function set `arg->value = c;` directly.

Comment: @nitzanms thanks for your reply, i'm sure that test hangs. Because the simulator logs some performance parameters in each 100000 instructions. As long as the simulator continues, it always prints that log. Also when I debug it, I observed that arch. simulator waits at the line that it needs to receive an instruction from PIN tool through a port.

Actually this was the minimal example but it escalated quickly, sorry!

Comment: @caf thanks for your reply, yes you are right, i put that valuePointer to be able to access the data from outside of the thread but `arg->value` should work for it as well. I don't think that it is related with the problem though.

Comment: @agy did you try to run the application with Pin, but without the hardware simulator tool? This may help narrow in on what's causing the issue.

Comment: @nitzanms debugging simulator is performed in 2 separate parts. To simulate frontend, where PIN tool was implemented, I use the following command: `/home/agy/mcsim/pin/intel64/bin/pinbin -pause_tool 10 -t /home/agy/mcsim/Pthread/mypthreadtool -port 50051 -skip_first 10000 -- McSim/JacNoBoost/JACCARD` and from another console window I run the following command and attach the previous process when gdb starts `gdb /home/agy/mcsim/Pthread/mypthreadtool`. Is this what you meant?
When I do this, at some point it freezes and if i try to backtrace it, it gives me lots of numbers and question marks.

Comment: @nitzanms i edited the question a bit according to changes that I observed on the program after I added mutex on reading operation. Could you please look at the new version of that function? Thanks

Comment: @agy I'm away from home so it took me some time to see your reply. What I meant was to run pin (it's an underlying technology for mcsim) without the mypthreadtool bit.

Comment: @agy also, is mypthreadtool something you wrote or something that comes with mcsima+? I'm asking because you shouldn't use pthread when writing pintools.

Comment: @nitzanms yes mypthreadtool is the front end of mcsima+. What do you mean by saying "you shouldn't use pthread when writing pintools"?

Comment: McSimA+ is using pin as an underlying technology. Programs using pin as an engine are also called pin tools. If the tool is unmodified by you then it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I made it work by doing the following modifications in the function which each thread executes (jaccard_visit):

1. Wrap read operations of global variables with mutex_lock
2. Remove function calls and implement them inline
3. Avoid using set, instead use string or char array
4. Separate destination and source of string functions

The following code works pretty well:

```
void * jaccard_visit(void *arg){
    thread_args * args = (thread_args *) arg;
    int id = args->id;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : thread started" << endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&payload_mutex);
    string str1 = my_graph[args->index1].payload_text;
    string str2 = my_graph[args->index2].payload_text;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&payload_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : payload texts are read" << endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    int stringLength = str1.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < stringLength;) {
            if (str1[i] == str1[j]) 
                str1[j] = str1[--stringLength];
            else   
                j++;
        }
    }
    string set1 = str1.substr(0, stringLength);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : unique chars of first node were extracted" << endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    stringLength = str2.length() - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < stringLength;) {
            if (str2[i] == str2[j]) 
                str2[j] = str2[--stringLength];
            else   
                j++;
        }
    }
    string set2 = str2.substr(0, stringLength);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);    cout << id << " : unique chars of second node were extracted" << endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    int intersection_index = 0;
    int union_index = 0;
    for (int i = 0 ; i < set1.length() ; i++){
        bool exists_in_set2 = false;
        for (int j = 0 ; j < set2.length() && exists_in_set2 == false; j++){
            if (set1[i] == set2[j]) {
                intersection_index ++;
                exists_in_set2 = true;
            }
        }
        if (!exists_in_set2) {
            union_index ++;
        }       
    }
    union_index += set2.length();

    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);  cout << id << " : set1={" << set1 << "}, set2={" << set2 << "}" << endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex);  cout << id << " : |n|=" << intersection_index << ", |u|=" << union_index <<  endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    double similarity = ((double) intersection_index / union_index); 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&cout_mutex); cout<<id<<" : similarity is: " << similarity << endl;    pthread_mutex_unlock(&cout_mutex);

    pthread_mutex_lock(&indices_mutex); 
    my_graph[args->index1].jaccardList[args->index2] = similarity;
    my_graph[args->index2].jaccardList[args->index1] = similarity;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&indices_mutex); 
    return NULL;

}
```